# Рваные края в SVG

Tags: svg

Имеется вот такой переливающийся текст на основе linear-gradient сделанный в svg , но так же заметил погрешности ...наглядно :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 93 40">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient  id="linearGradient914">
      <stop id="stop910"
         offset="0"
         style="stop-color:yellow;" />
      <stop  id="stop912"
         offset="1"
         style="stop-color:red;" />
    </linearGradient>


    <linearGradient
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       y2="168.58255"
       x2="-127.96807"
       y1="168.58255"
       x1="-227.84294"
       id="linearGradient916"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient914" />
  </defs>
  <g  transform="translate(210.09778,-163.31157)"  id="layer1">
    <text  transform="scale(0.92185611,1.084768)" id="text817" y="178.24792" x="-228.11203"  style="font-size:41px;line-height:41px;">
  <tspan style="font-family:Gabriola;fill:url(#linearGradient916);" y="178.24792"  x="-228.11203"  id="tspan815">свобода</tspan>
 </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

как видно у текста рваные края как будто это растровая графика в Google Chrome но в Firefox и в IE11 этого нету...

**Что нужно сделать что бы этого не было в Google Chrome** ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация : https://stackoverflow.com/q/51210969/6339052

Comment: Что-то не вижу никаких краёв

Comment: @Arthur  я скрин выложил

Comment: Странно, у меня нет такого. С любым текстом пробовал

Comment: @Arthur у тебя Габриола установлен в системе ?

Comment: конечно, у меня нет такого

Comment: @Arthur с любым текстом и с любым шрифтом

Comment: Тоже не вижу таких краёв https://jsfiddle.net/p4g36zwm/embedded/result,html,js,css/

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft   я же скриншот не выдумал же...чё  косяк у меня одного ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский я понимаю. Но не скриншот с данного мною примера. Что может быть. 1 - Косячный шрифт в системе. Попробуйте удалить его. Чтобы не ставить все шрифты в систему, я пользуюсь FontMassive менеджером. Удалив шрифт перезапустить браузер и проверить по ссылке на фидле. Если косяка нет, то скачать подгружаемый шрифт. Файл стилей шрифта там есть

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft  я на SO дополнил а здесь забыл - в общем я менял семейство шрифта и размер и даже убрал градиент оставил просто сплошную заливку - как была лесенка так и осталась

Comment: Попробуйте удалить шрифт из системы. Ссылка на FontMassive https://yadi.sk/d/vd2hZ5jztxo3m Очень удобно инициализировать определённый набор под проект. Особенно при работе с Adobe PhotoShop, Illustrator, etc

Comment: Мой скриншот http://take.ms/qdFGF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевёл шрифт в кривые Безье и текст градиентом стал отображаться отлично, в поиске решения помог [Moskus](https://toster.ru/q/544141?e=6660695#clarification_579193),